# How to run create-react-app without git (skipping git)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, create-react-app

I don't want git initialized in my folder when I create react app by

```
npx create-react-app appName
```

When I was working with Angular, it was comparatively easier by just typing the command

```
ng new my-app --skip-git
```

Can anyone please tell me the related command for React? I tried searching but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: "I don't want git initialized in my folder when I create react app by" - why not?

Comment: @Dai , because I am placing my frontend with backend under the same folder and I have git initialized in the backend folder, If I initialize another git inside the frontend folder, it will create a dispute with the other initialized git.

Comment: It's understandable if he/she wants to add it to some existing project or a future project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9502) for your case.

TL;DR: There are no current plans to include such an option. The React developers recommend you run `rm -rf .git` after `npx create-react-app appName` to achieve these results.

Comment: maybe some people don't know that the command only works in  bash terminal

Comment: If you are using windows, you can use `rmdir /S .git` after creating react app in root folder. It simply deletes **.git** file.

Answer (score 2):

Try `npx create-react-app --skip-git`.
If this is not working delete the **.git** folder manually .

Answer (score 2):

I had case where I have nodejs folder and I wanted to create react frontend project folder inside react project folder. I did it using this command `npx create-react-app projectname --skip-git`

Comment: This worked for me when creating a react app in an existing git repo, except I used `create-react-app` instead of `react-create-app`.

Comment: My bad, I have changed order mistakenly. But I have corrected it now. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

They've added a `--skip-git-init` flag to the `react-native init` command that should do what you're looking for ([see the PR here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/2177)).

So the command would look like this:

```
npx react-native init myProject --skip-git-init
```