# How to skip git setup while creating a next app via cli npx create-next-app?

Tags: git, next.js

On top of [How to create react app without git (skipping git)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008696/how-to-create-react-app-without-git-skipping-git), I would like to know if there are any ways to create a NextJS app without the git part by passing flags via the CLI like how we have with NestJS app `nest new [app-name] --skip-git`