# How to resolve create-react-app error [Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, create-react-app

When running this command to create a React app, it creates the app, but it's also giving me an error.  What does this error mean and how do I resolve it?

```
npx create-react-app mynews-app

231 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:957:15)
    at tryGitInit (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactJs\mynews-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:46:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\sapar\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ReactJs\mynews-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:276:7)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:307:38)
    at node:internal/process/execution:79:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 13968,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Installing template dependencies using npm...

added 55 packages in 9s

231 packages are looking for funding
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd mynews-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

Comment: That's because you haven't installed GIT on your system, it tries to create a GIT repository along with the installation of React. Looking at the other results, the project has been created succesfully.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008696/how-to-create-react-app-without-git-skipping-git

Answer (score 2):

`create-react-app` assumes you have `git` installed and configured, and uses `git` to create a git repository.

Ensure you have git installed on your machine. Run `git` in your terminal to verify. Install `git` if it's not installed. Once installed, configure the `git` user name and email:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Username"
$ git config --global user.email youremail@example.com
```

Comment: it's required to download git? if YES then why it's required