# Not able to push the react folder which is acting as submodule to git

Tags: git, github

I have made an ecommerce folder, inside which I have defined two folders:

1. `client` folder which is actually a react folder which I made by using

   ```shell
   npx create-react-app client
   ```
2. `server` folder which contains my backend data

When I am pushing ecommerce to the git, server is getting pushed as usual but the client folder is not getting pushed and is showing as grey.

When I searched for it, it showed  react app is by default a git folder, so I tried pushing all the folders and files inside client separately and then pushing it from the ecommerce folder which didn't work

I even tried making client not a git folder but it is also not working

I need to push the code of client folder as well because I am making a lot of mistakes building ecommerce site and my code it breaking again and again so I am needing to rollback to previous working state

Comment: Have you by any chance added `client` to your `.gitignore` file? You mentioned git submodules in the title but nowhere in your question. How is that relevant?

Comment: If the `create-react-app` tool has created a `client/.git` directory, you'll need to delete it... `rm -rf client/.git`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create react app without git (skipping git)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008696/how-to-create-react-app-without-git-skipping-git)

Comment: @Phil When I am trying to delete .git directory inside client and using the same command as you mentioned , it is showing as -rf not recognized

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, it's `rmdir /S client\.git` (I think)

Comment: When I was searching for this online, it showed as since client is inside ecommerce folder and ecommerce as well as client have .git directory in them , client will act as submodule to ecommerce

Comment: rmdir /S client\.git worked , Thanks